# Timber + Woocommerce : display product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

I'm trying to create a shop page and display all the woocommerce products categories rather than the products. With "Timber::get_terms('product_cat');" I'm able to get some informations about categories but I'm stuck to retrieve the thumbnail.

Woocommerce.php :

```
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    $context['category'] = Timber::get_terms('product_cat');
    $context['title'] = single_term_title( '', false );
}
```

archive.twig :

```
       {% for categories in category %}
        {{categories.title}}
        {{categories.thumbnail.src}}             
       {% endfor %}
```

I also tried this (found on another thread)  But it didn't work :

```
{% for categories in category %} 
{% set categories_image = TimberImage(categories.thumbnail) %}
<img src="{{ categories_image.src }}" alt="{{ categories_image.alt }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it via the meta option:

```
{% set categories_image = Image(categories.meta('thumbnail_id')) %}
```